# Issue with Frames in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer-10, frameset

The application which am working on has many JSPs which have many framesets. 
The application is working fine in Internet Explorer 8. 
Whereas the screen gets freezed when a JSP containing Frames are present in Internet Explorer 10.

Please find the part of Code which contains Frameset.

```
<FRAMESET id="xframe" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="285,*,0,0" >
<FRAME src="<%=JspPath%>basicempty.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="WTicketDetailsHeader" scrolling="no"  noresize>
<FRAME src="<%=JspPath%>basicempty.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="WTicketDetailsResult" scrolling="yes" noresize>
<FRAME src="<%=JspPath%>basicempty.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="empty_result"       scrolling="no"  noresize>
<FRAME src="<%=JspPath%>basicempty.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="toolbox_result"       scrolling="no"  noresize>
</FRAMESET>
```

Comment: Please note that using frames in this way is really *really* out-dated -- the `frameset` and `frame` tags aren't even in the current HTML specs. If you're writing new code, you should not be using frames at all.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Could you please let me know the template? It would be really helpful.

Comment: @Spudley they're mentioned in the HTML5 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/rendering.html#frames-and-framesets

Comment: @RowlandShaw: fair enough. However that doesn't stop them being deprecated; notice that the links on that page for the `frame` and `frameset` elements take you to the appropriately named `obsolete.html` page, so I think my point stands.